# TypeError from theano While using 3D numpy array

Tags: python, theano

I am trying something similar to code below

```
datax=theano.shared(value=rng.rand(5,500,45))
x=T.dmatrix('x')
i=T.lscalar('i')
W=theano.shared(value=rng.rand(90,45,500))
Hb=theano.shared(value=np.zeros(90))
w_v_bias=T.dot(W,x).sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1)+Hb
z=theano.function([i],w_v_bias,givens={x:datax[i*5:(i+1)*5]})

z(0)
```

Theano is giving me a TypeError with msg:

> Cannot convert Type TensorType(float64, 3D) (of Variable Subtensor{int64:int64:}.0) into Type TensorType(float64, matrix). You can try to manually convert Subtensor{int64:int64:}.0 into a TensorType(float64, matrix)

What I am doing wrong here?

Edit

As mentioned by daniel changing x to dtensor3 will result in another error.

> ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 5, input[1].shape[1] = 90)
>
> Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{add,no_inplace}(Sum{axis=[1], acc_dtype=float64}.0, DimShuffle{x,0}.0)

Another way is to modify my train function but then I won't be able to do batch learning.

```
  z=theano.function([x],w_v_bias)
  z(datax[0])
```

I am trying to implement  RBM with integer values for visible units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it after few hit and trials.

What I needed was to change

```
x=T.dmatrix('x')
w_v_bias=T.dot(W,x).sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1)+Hb
```

to

```
x=T.dtensor3('x')
w_v_bias=T.dot(x,W).sum(axis=3).sum(axis=1)+Hb
```

Now it produces (5,90) array after adding Hb elementwise to each of the five vectors of dot product.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `datax` is a 3D tensor and `datax[index*5:(index+1)*5]` is also a 3D tensor but you're trying to assign that to `x` which is a 2D tensor (i.e. a matrix).

Changing

```
x = T.dmatrix('x')
```

to

```
x = T.dtensor3('x')
```

solves this problem but creates a new one because the dimensions of W and x don't match up to perform the dot product. It's unclear what the desired outcome is.

Comment: Hello daniel, I tried your method and  dot product returns np.array(90,5) after adding along axis 3&1. As for what i need is np.array(90,1) to add Hb elementwise. I thought that dataX[0],dataX[1] , ... is to be operated  sequentially during computation